# Undefined reference to QVideoSurfaceFormat constructor

Tags: c++, qt, linker, multimedia

I am programming for Ubutu linux, and am tryi9ng to display video. However, i have run into a problem:
 i am not able to create instances of QVideoSurfaceFormat, due to the following error:

```
undefined reference to `QVideoSurfaceFormat::QVideoSurfaceFormat(QSize const&, QVideoFrame::AVPixelFormat, QAbstractVideoBuffer::HandleType)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am guessing that the problem lies inQt Multimedia binaries, somewhere. But in the compile output there is the following:

g++  -o LPR_Demo main.o mainwindow.o imgProcessor.o qpicturelabel.o aboutdialog.o state.o videowidget.o videowidgetsurface.o videoplayer.o qt_videoreader.o roidialog.o recognitionresult.o ffmpeg_reader.o moc_mainwindow.o moc_imgProcessor.o moc_aboutdialog.o moc_videowidget.o moc_videowidgetsurface.o moc_videoplayer.o moc_qt_videoreader.o moc_roidialog.o moc_recognitionresult.o qrc_lpr_Res.o    -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -L/usr/X11R6/lib -L/home/truskov/development/lprsdk/LPR/bin -lLPR -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lswscale -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu **-lQtMultimediaKit** -lQtOpenGL -lQtGui -lQtNetwork -lQtCore -lGL -lpthread

where QtMultimediaKit library seems to be in place.

My .pro file goes like this:

```
QT       += core gui
win32:QT+= multimedia
unix {
QT+= mobility multimediakit
MOBILITY = multimedia
CONFIG += mobility

}
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = LPR_Demo
TEMPLATE = app
```

however, when qmake runs, i get following messages:

Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: mobility
Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: multimediakit

What could cause this? How can it be solved?

Comment: A few ideas: It looks like you're building a 32-bit version of the binary. Is it on 64-bit Ubuntu? Are you sure you have the 32-bit version of the Qt multimedia stuff installed? Next, look for libQtMultimediaKit{-version}.so on the filesystem. Run 'nm -D' against the file and filter through 'c++filt'. Search for the function prototype you care about. Is it there? Does it have a capital 'T' next to it? If either of those questions is 'no', then that's a problem.